# Faster String GetHashCode (e.g. using Multicore or GPU)

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

According to http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=463663 , C#'s `getHashCode` function in 3.5 is implemented as:

```
public override unsafe int GetHashCode()
{
    fixed (char* str = ((char*) this))
    {
        char* chPtr = str;
        int num = 0x15051505;
        int num2 = num;
        int* numPtr = (int*) chPtr;
        for (int i = this.Length; i > 0; i -= 4)
        {
            num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
            if (i <= 2)
            {
                break;
            }
            num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
            numPtr += 2;
        }
        return (num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
    }
}
```

I am curious if anyone can come up with a function which returns the same results, but is faster.  It is OK to increase the overall starting and resource overhead of the main application.  Requiring a one-time initialization (per application execution, not per call or per string) is OK.

Note that unlike Microsoft, considerations like, "doing it this way will make everything else slower and has costs that make this method stupid!" can be ignored, so it is possible that even assuming Microsoft's is perfect, it can be beaten by doing something "stupid."

This purely an exercise in my own curiosity and will not be used in real code.

Examples of ideas I've thought of:

- Using multiple cores (calculating num2 and num independently)
- Using the gpu

Comment: Multiple cores or GPU may increase speed only with *HUGE* strings.

Comment: Have you tried either of your ideas (#1 wouldn't be too hard to code up)?  If so, post what you've found...

Comment: Any particular reason to need it to return the same thing? The `GetHashCode` algorithm is implementation-defined for all types according to ECMA-335, and in order to reimplement `GetHashCode` for string then you're already using a different CLR implementation.

Comment: What about on startup you store the pre-calculated hash of every known string in a dictionary. The the lookup each time will be very quick ;-)

Comment: Admittedly you'd need loads of memory and your program would take forever to load, but you could use a splash screen!!!!

Comment: We should also pre-compute the hash code of ints !

Comment: I just noticed a problem with my "optimisation". You have to compute a hash to look up the item in the dictionary. So your computing a hash to enable you to find the hash value, genius ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads and GPU most certainly will introduce overhead greater than possible performance boost. The approach that could be justified is using SIMD instruction sets, such as SSE. However, it would require testing whether this partcular instruction set is available, which may cost. It will also bring boost on long strings only.

If you want to try it, consider testing [Mono support for SIMD](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html) before diving into C or assembly. Read [here](http://blog.xpdm.us/2009/10/01/skein-threefish-and-mono-simd-part-1/) about development possibilities and gotchas.

Answer (score 3):

One way to make a function go faster is to take special cases into account.
A function with variable size inputs has special cases based on size.

Going parallel only makes sense when the the cost of going parallel
is smaller than the gain, and for this kind of computation it is likely
that the string would have to be fairly large to overcome the cost
of forking a parallel thread.   But implementing that isn't hard;
basically you need a test for this.Length exceeding an empirically
determined threshold, and then forking multiple threads to compute
hashes on substrings, with a final step composing the subhashes into
a final hash.    Implementation left for the reader.

Modern processors also have SIMD instructions, which can process up
to 32 (or 64) bytes in a single instruction.   This would allow you
to process the string in 32 (16 bit character) chunks in one-two
SIMD instructions per chunk; and then fold the 64 byte result into
a single hashcode at the end.   This is likely to be extremely fast
for strings of any reasonable size.    The implementation of this
from C# is harder, because one doesn't expect a virtual machine
to provide provide easy (or portable) access to the SIMD instructions
that you need.   Implementation also left for the reader.
EDIT:  Another answer suggests that Mono system does provide
SIMD instruction access.

Having said that, the particular implementation exhibited is pretty stupid.
The key observation is that the loop checks the limit twice on every iteration.
One can solve that problem by checking the end condition cases in advance,
and executing a loop that does the correct number of iterations.
One can do better than that by using
[Duffs device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)
to jump into an unrolled loop of N iterations.  This gets rid of
the loop limit checking overhead for N-1 iterations.   That modification
would be very easy and surely be worth the effort to implement.

EDIT: You can also combine the SIMD idea and the loop unrolling idea to enable processing many chunks of 8/16 characters in a few SIMD instrucions.

For languages that can't jump into loops, one can do the equivalent of
Duff's device by simply peeling off the initial cases.   A shot at
how to recode the original code using the loop peeling approach is the following:

```
    public override unsafe int GetHashCode()
    {
        fixed (char* str = ((char*) this))
        {
            const int N=3; // a power of two controlling number of loop iterations
            char* chPtr = str;
            int num = 0x15051505;
            int num2 = num;
            int* numPtr = (int*) chPtr;
            count = this.length;
            unrolled_iterations = count >> (N+1); // could be 0 and that's OK
            for (int i = unrolled_iterations; i > 0; i--)
            {
               // repeat 2**N times
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[2];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[3]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[4];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[5]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[6];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[7]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[8];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[9]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[10];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[11]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[12];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[13]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[14];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[15]; }
               numPtr += 16;
            }
            if (count & ((1<<N)-1))
            {
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[2];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[3]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[4];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[5]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[6];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[7]; }
               numPtr += 8;
            }
            if (count & ((1<<(N-1))-1))
            {
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1]; }
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[2];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[3]; }
               numPtr += 4;
            }
            if (count & ((1<<(N-2)-1))
            {
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                 num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1]; }
               numPtr += 2;
            }
            // repeat N times and finally:
            if { count & (1) }
            {
               { num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
               // numPtr += 1;
            }

            return (num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
        }
    }
```

I haven't compiled or tested this code, but the idea is right.
It depends on the compiler doing reasonable constant folding
and address arithmetic.

I tried to code this to preserve the exact hash value of the original,
but IMHO that isn't really a requirement.
It would be even simpler and a tiny bit faster if it didn't use
the num/num2 stunt, but simply updated num for each character.

---

Corrected version (by Brian) as a static function:

```
    public static unsafe int GetHashCodeIra(string x)
    {
        fixed (char* str = x.ToCharArray())
        {
            const int N = 2; // a power of two controlling number of loop iterations
            char* chPtr = str;
            int num = 0x15051505;
            int num2 = num;
            int* numPtr = (int*)chPtr;
            int count = (x.Length+1) / 2;
            int unrolled_iterations = count >> (N+1); // could be 0 and that's OK
            for (int i = unrolled_iterations; i > 0; i--)
            {  // repeat 2**N times
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
                }
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[2];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[3];
                }
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[4];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[5];
                }
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[6];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[7];
                }
                numPtr += 8;
            }
            if (0 != (count & ((1 << N) )))
            {
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
                }
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[2];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[3];
                }
                numPtr += 4;
            }
            if (0 != (count & ((1 << (N - 1) ))))
            {
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                    num2 = (((num2 << 5) + num2) + (num2 >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[1];
                }
                numPtr += 2;
            }
            // repeat N times and finally:
            if (1 == (count & 1))
            {
                {
                    num = (((num << 5) + num) + (num >> 0x1b)) ^ numPtr[0];
                    // numPtr += 1;
                }
            }

            return (num + (num2 * 0x5d588b65));
        }
    }
```

Comment: (after fixing it), I tested this.  It made no difference, either in debug or compiled mode.  It helped a little on really long strings (more than 20 characters), and hurt a little on really short strings (less than 5 characters).  Not much difference, though.

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it; I didn't think it was wrong :-} One might try reversing the loop peeling steps: do the unit step first, and check so see if the string is short; then the two step,
then check for get out, etc.  This would make short strings run
faster at virtually no impact for the longer ones.
I'd also simplify the code to avoid the num/num2 dichotomy; the computation might run entirely in the registers in that case.

Comment: ... so what did you actually measure? The time to run a compuation in which hashing was involved, or the time to do the hashing itself?

Comment: ... and I wouldn't consider 20 character strings as "long"; you'd never be able to parallelize this for 20 characters.  1000 characters is long.   How does it do on 1000 character strings?

Comment: @Ira: Just the hashing itself.

Comment: @Ira: Here's a corrected copy.  And yes, I know I reduced the unrolling by a factor of 2.

Comment: @Brian: 1) What's the reason for using char* str = x.ToCharArray()) rather than the original (char*) cast?  Are you sure the the ToCharArray() doesn't actually copy the original string (which would kill most of the performance gain)?  2) How much you unroll it depends how how small you want to drive the loop overhead.  I did lots of unrolled loop coding like this on smaller machines and found that 16x-32x unrolls provided measurable differences when the operands got long enough.

Comment: @Ira: #1 No particular reason.  #2: Yeah, I had no particular reason to change that.

Comment: @Brian: I'm serious, check that ToCharArray() doesn't do a a copy.  Strings are immutable.   Char arrays are not; how can ToCharArray return a reference to a mutable thing using the same storage as the string?

Comment: @Ira: 1: It can return a reference to a mutable thing because it is unsafe. 2: I can't change it to (char*) x because that gives a cast error.  However, I used the same code in the "normal" version for testing, so my timing measurements are consistent.

Comment: @Brian... and how did it do on 1000 character strings, which is the point of your original question?

Comment: @Ira: Did you confirm that the compiler isn't unrolling the loop anyhow before going to this effort?  Loop unrolling has been around as a compiler optimization for quite a while now...

Comment: @Ira, @Brian: Guys, `ToCharArray` [definitely makes a copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx). Being in an unsafe context does not change the implementation of a method! The correct way to fix a `char*` pointer on a string is `fixed (char* ptr = str)`: pretty simple.

Comment: @Eric J: Compilers sometimes unroll loops.  In this case, the loop content was unnecessarily expensive, and the problem was to restructure the loop to get rid of the extra test.  I don't think most compilers will do this.

Answer (score 1):

Given that strings are immutable, the first thing that I would consider is caching the return result.

Comment: It takes memory and it's usefull only if GetHashCode is called multiple times on the same instance.

Comment: The question was about speed, not memory use ;)

Comment: When we talk about primitive types, speed and memory are linked... But you are right, the question was only about speed of a particular algorithm. Anyway, it still helps only when GetHashCode is called multiple times on the same instance.

Comment: To cache the result, you have to look up the result based on the argument.  So you'll need to hash the argument to look up the cached answer... oops, that was the problem we were trying to avoid.  I don't think you can reasonably do this.

Comment: @Ira: er, there is no argument. The cache would be on the instance of the string. There is nothing to check except whether you've already calculated the result. if (_hashCode != 0) return _hashCode;

Comment: who downvoted this; this is the sanest/most practical solution posted

Comment: @Kent: so your solution adds a cache data slot to the string data structure?  OK, now I understand how you can avoid computing the hash value after it has been computed. The OP wanted a faster hashing function, period.

Comment: @Ira: as stated in the question, this was an exercise in curiosity, so I'm not sure why you're being so pedantic. The OP did not want a faster hashing function. He asked for a hash method that returns the same result but faster. My solution will do exactly that for subsequent calls. When is the last time you measured the performance of a method by executing it once?

Comment: @Kent:  At the point in time that the hash value is needed, somebody, somewhere had to compute it.  Less work is less work,  even if you cache the answer.  I think we both understand the other viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could parallelize this however the problem you will run into is that threads, CUDA, etc have overheads associated with them. Even if you use a thread pool, if your strings are not very large, let's say a typical string is 128-256 characters (probably less than this) you will probably still end up making each call to this function taking longer than it did originally.

Now, if you were dealing with very large strings, then yes it would improve your time. The simple algorithm is "embarrassingly parallel."

Answer (score 0):

I think all of your suggested approaches are very inefficient compared to the current implementation.

**Using GPU:**
The string data needs to be transferred to the GPU and the result back, which takes a lot of time. GPU's are very fast, but only when comparing floating point calculations, which aren't used here. All operations are on Integers, for which x86 CPU power is decent.

**Using Another CPU Core:**
This would involve creating a separate thread, locking down memory and synchronizing the thread requesting the Hash Code. The incurred overhead simply outweighs the benefits of parallel processing.

If you would want to calculate Hash values of thousands of strings in one go, things might look a little different, but I can't imagine a scenario where this would justify implementing a faster `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: If you want to calculate Hash values od thousands of strings, you don't need to re-implement GetHashCode, just call the default GetHashCode on different threads for each string.

Comment: True, but even if you had a thousand threads, you'd still want the basic code for the hashing to run as fast as you could make a sequential version of it run.

Answer (score 0):

Each step in the computation builds on the result of the previous step.  If iterations of the loop run out of order, you will get a *different result* (the value of *num* from the previous iteration serves as input to the next iteration).

For that reason, any approach (multithreading, massively parallel execution on a GPU) that runs steps in parallel will generally skew the result.

Also, I would be surprised if the previously discussed loop unrolling is not already being done internally by the compiler to the extent that it actually makes a difference in execution time (compilers tend to be smarter than the average programmer these days, and loop unrolling has been around for a really long time as a compiler optimization technique).